# Cannot find module 'agent-base' in vercel deployment

Tags: javascript, vercel

the **error** log

```
Cannot find module 'agent-base'
Require stack:
- /var/task/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/index.js
- /var/task/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js
- /var/task/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/index.js
- /var/task/node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js
- /var/task/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
- /var/task/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js
- /var/task/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/index.js
- /var/task/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/apis/abusiveexperiencereport/index.js
- /var/task/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/apis/index.js
- /var/task/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/googleapis.js
- /var/task/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/index.js
- /var/task/index.js
- /var/task/___now_launcher.js
- /var/runtime/index.mjs
```

Did you forget to add it to "dependencies" in `package.json`?
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 846.22 ms    Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError

my package.json

```
{

  "dependencies": {
    "agent-base": "^7.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "express": "^4.18.3",
    "googleapis": "^133.0.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  }
}
```

and vercel.json

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "index.js",
      "use": "@now/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "index.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the same issue by replacing`"use": "@now/node"` with `"use": "@vercel/node"`.
It turns out [@now/node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@now/node) is deprecated.

Please be noted that googleapis is not designed for browser, but more for the backend code, see [this github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/3360).